# How to set location of IE toolbar created using BHO and Band Objects

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I had to create a Toolbar for IE using C#. After much research in the internet and few examples from code project, I have created one. Even the horrible installer/uninstaller part is done. My toolbar basically Searchbar which does a search of the things that the user enter inside the text box. Im using Google and Bing as the search engine of which the user can choose anyone as per his/her convinience. However I would like to make few changes to the Toolbar and I'm wondering how to go ahead in that.

1. After installing the toolbar I'm finding it somewhere near the MenuBar(after the Tools and Help menu). Is there a way to change the location of the toolbar in IE Browser using C#
2. I would like to create an Icon somewhere in this area
   [image]
   How should i approach towards this?
3. I also want to add an uninstall button on which when the user clicks will uninstall the toolbar from IE.

So far I havent been able to achieve any of this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of IE window with your band and point the place on the screenshot where your band should be?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov can you tell me how to find the installation location of the BHO as i want to redirect to a html page which will be in the installation folder of BHO